# Deleting the last x amount of indexes in an Numpy Array Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, indexing

How could I write a function that deletes the last X amount of indexes within a numpy array without using a for loop?

```
to_be_deleted_indexs= 4
A = np.array([2,3,55,6,7,3,2,5,6,7,11])
```

expected output:

```
[2,3,55,6,7,3,2]
```

Comment: Do you want to physically remove the last four elements from A or get a copy of A without the last four elements?

Comment: Physical not a copy I would have done `A[:]` otherwise

Comment: You can't "physically" remove.  `A1=A[:-4]` is a `view` without the last x.  `A` still has all values.  **edit** I take that back, in some cases you can do `A.resize(7)`.  But usually we just slice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `resize` method *as long as* `A` does not share memory with any other array:

```
A.resize(A.shape[0] - to_be_deleted_indexs)
#array([ 2,  3, 55,  6,  7,  3,  2])
```